# Access iframe node given element node inside iframe using Javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Say I'm given an HTML element node, such as a

```
    <div id = "content"></div>
```

and that's contained in an iframe. It's passed in to me as a node. I want to be able to get the iframe node that the element's in -- there's no specific id and I want to be able to access it just from the element node. I've tried

```
  elNode.window
```

and

```
  elNode.parent
```

But obviously that gives me undefined. I'm also passed in the current window, but trying

```
 curWindow.parent
```

just passes me in the window, so that was led to no avail. I really just want to get the iframe from the element node. If anyone has any pointers, that's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is due to the same-origin policy: the browser won’t allow the original script to inspect the contents of the cross-origin document. more details about sop https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy. Generally, there are following ways to solves this issue:

1. using  element has never really been subject to the same-origin policy: it will download and execute any script, regardless of origin.
2. cross-document messaging,allows a script from one document to pass textual messages to a script in another document, regardless of the script origins. Calling the postMessage() method on a Window object results in the asynchronous delivery of a message event (you can handle it with an onmessage event handler function) to the document in that window.
3. Cross-Origin Resource Sharing https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ : This draft standard extends HTTP with a new Origin: request header and a new Access-Control- Allow-Origin response header. It allows servers to use a header to explicitly list origins that may request a file or to use a wildcard and allow a file to be requested by any site.

   4. To support multi domain websites of this sort, you can use the domain property of the Document object . But, the domain value must have at least one dot in it; you cannot set it to “com” or any other top-level domain. for example ecar.car.com, pcar.car.com.  you can set the domain to car.com.

hope this can give you a kind of help

Comment: Wait, I'm using a friendly iframe -- is that still a problem?